# OpenCL host code for Bitonic Sort

Tags: sorting, opencl

Can anyone tell where can I find the host code of the OpenCL bitonic sort Algorithm given in the the book OpenCL in Action by Matthew Scarpino...?

Answer (score 2):

The code samples for the book can be found in the downloads section on the following page of the publisher's website: [Manning: OpenCL In Action](http://www.manning.com/scarpino2/)

Comment: Stackoverflow answers are meant to be standalone.  Please quote any relevant information from the link cited into your answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question